# TypeError: callBack is not a function in Jest test for updating state

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
export interface MyState {
    DetailData?: any;

    BookID?: string;

    GetDetail: () => void;

    ShowWindow: (id: string) => void;
    HideWindow: () => void;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, MyState> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            GetDetail: () => {
                // external call here that returns DATA 
                this.setState({ DetailData: DATA });
            }
            ShowWindow: (id: string) => {
                this.setState({ BookID: id }, () => this.state.GetDetail());
            },
            HideWindow: () => {
                this.setState({
                    BookID: undefined,
                    DetailData: undefined,
                });
            },
        };
    }
}
```

I have the above component where calling `ShowWindow` updates the state of BookID with some ID and in the setState callback fires `this.state.GetDetail`.

I'm trying to test it in my Jest test like so:

```
it("Should update state with the BookID and call GetDetail", () => {
    const control = enzyme.mount(<MyComponent  />);

    const bookID= "ID123";

    control.state().ShowWindow(bookID);
    expect(control.state().BookID).toEqual(bookID);
});
```

But this returns a `TypeError: callBack is not a function` error. How can I fix and properly test this?